# Android overlap Recycler View with Collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, overlapping

I want to overlap the first item in the **RecyclerView** with the **CollapsingToolbar** and also while I scroll, the item needs to be fixed to the CollapsingToolbar, I have tried the following.

> **Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/colay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_color">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <info.devexchanges.parallaxheaderlistview.FixCollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:text="Hello there"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_20"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/dummy_text"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </info.devexchanges.parallaxheaderlistview.FixCollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">      
       //app:behavior_overlapTop="100dp"
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_layout" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have tried using even `app:behavior_overlapTop="100dp"` in my NestedScrollView, but then the scrolling animation does not happen as required. Also, there is an extra space after the **RecyclerView** that is added at the bottom. This happens even after removing the **Negative Margin** I have read the other posts but nothing seems to work. Can someone please provide me with a proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
```

If you give `enterAlways` `app:behavior_overlapTop` will not work, try the above line of code.